# Google maps android on cluster items click not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my google maps fragment, 
I used this to add my item as clusters

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ContactInfo>(getActivity(), googleMap);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.addItem(myItem);
```

Now, I can manage to set onClusterClickListener by

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
```

By using the above code, I can detect when I click those clusters,
However, when I click those seperate markers, this does not work.

How to detect those seperate markers I added to clusterManager?

Comment: My suggestion is don't use 'Android Marker Clustering Utility' in place use 'android map extension'  cause default library cannot handle 1000 markers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setOnClusterClickListener` is invoked when a Cluster is tapped.

You also need to set `setOnClusterItemClickListener` which is

> Sets a callback that's invoked when an individual ClusterItem is
>   tapped. Note: For this listener to function, the ClusterManager must
>   be added as a click listener to the map.

And be sure to implement `ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<T extends ClusterItem>`

Comment: Thank you, it seems I also need to add   googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);a

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 3):

**Try This custom Class.**

```
private class PersonRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Person> {

        public PersonRenderer() {
            super(MainActivity.this, mMap, mClusterManager1);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Person person, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            Debug.e("call", "onBeforeClusterItemRendered");
            // Draw a single person.
            // Set the info window to show their name.


        }


        @Override
        protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<Person> cluster) {
            Debug.e("call", "shouldRenderAsCluster");
            return cluster.getSize() > 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered(Person clusterItem, Marker marker) {
            super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
            Debug.e("call", "onClusterItemRendered");

        }
    }
```

**onClusterClick**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<Person> cluster) {
        Debug.e("call", "onClusterClick");

        // Show a toast with some info when the cluster is clicked.
        String firstName = cluster.getItems().iterator().next().name;
//        Toast.makeText(this, cluster.getSize() + " (including " + firstName + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Zoom in the cluster. Need to create LatLngBounds and including all the cluster items
        // inside of bounds, then animate to center of the bounds.

        // Create the builder to collect all essential cluster items for the bounds.
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
        for (ClusterItem item : cluster.getItems()) {
            builder.include(item.getPosition());
        }
        // Get the LatLngBounds
        final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();



        // Animate camera to the bounds
        try {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**onClusterInfoWindowClick**

```
 @Override
    public void onClusterInfoWindowClick(Cluster<Person> cluster) {
        Debug.e("call", "onClusterInfoWindowClick");
        // Does nothing, but you could go to a list of the users.
//        clickedCluster = cluster;
    }
```

**onClusterItemClick**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(Person item) {
        // Does nothing, but you could go into the user's profile page, for example.
        Debug.e("call", "onClusterItemClick");

        clickedClusterItem = item;

        return false;
    }
```

**onClusterItemInfoWindowClick**

```
  @Override
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(Person item) {
        // Does nothing, but you could go into the user's profile page, for example.
        Debug.e("call", "onClusterItemInfoWindowClick");

    }
```

Comment: This is very easy google sample https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering