# How to get click on the android cluster group?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, markerclusterer

I am not able to click on the android cluster group, even after I tried different solutions.

The first solution was to split the cluster using the below solution:

```
override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<PlaceMedico>): Boolean {
        return cluster.size > 1
    }
```

It didn't work as some of the clusters are not splitting.

The second solution was to get click on the cluster group as shown below screenshot, but I am getting click only in the marker, not the cluster:

```
clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener { item ->
                return@setOnClusterItemClickListener false
}
```

I need to click on the cluster group, to show data of each item in the cluster on a custom view. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you describe what you mean by "cluster"? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **setOnClusterClickListener**

```
clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener { item ->
                ..........
}
```

Check this question, is the opposite of your problem

[Google maps android on cluster items click not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965946/google-maps-android-on-cluster-items-click-not-working)